# How to simulate DOM for Rhino / Java 6 script engine

Tags: java, javascript, dom

When using Rhino / Java 6's script engine:

```
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
```

My problem is when I evaluate some scripts (normally written for the browser environment) the script engines crashes, due to "window" is not defined, which I fully understand since DOM is something created browser browsers.

However, what is the best way to simulate/mock the DOM environment (for example the "window" object).

Can this be done in Java (for example enabling something in ScriptEngine / Java) or do I have to include some kind of JavaScript that simulates the DOM?

What is currently the best solution to simulate this for Rhino/ Java 6 script engine?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to your question?

Comment: @SyedAqeelAshiq - Hey, this was 10 years ago, I can't remember anymore :)

Answer (score 2):

The DOM is a ***HUGE*** environment.  A complete simulation of everything in a browser is probably not available.  HOWEVER, take a look at [Bringing the Browser to the Server](http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/).  If this has been maintained, it may be enough for your purposes.